# Can I use "Engage List" instead of "Engagement List"?

Tags: meaning, expressions, meaning-in-context

In a sales context, can I use "Engage List" for a list of prospects instead of "Engagement List", which sounds more like a wedding list?

This is to be used in a web service to define a list of potential customers (i.e. prospects) with whom the user may "engage in social channels".

I know that in sales and marketing, "to engage", "customer engagement" etc. are broadly used, but I am not native and not sure how "Engage List" sounds. This is a key part of a new web service we are launching.

Comment: I would use "contact list" if it's only the identities, and "appointment list" or "calendar" or some such if it's a list of appointments.

Answer (score 2):

Engage List may be out of the frying pan and into obscurity.  Perhaps *Prospectives list* would get the idea across without being condescending?  Or even just a simple *Leads*?

Comment: Yeah, "leads" is good, and quite idiomatic in this context.

Comment: Definitely "Leads".

Answer (score 0):

'Prospects' or 'Prospects for engagement' sound cleaner to me. If you use a plural should not need the 'List' suffix.